# Calling methods on certain objects after parsing an XML file

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML file that I'd like to parse, and depending on what the values are, call certain methods on the corresponding objects in python.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<avengerState>
        <motors>
            <motor id="0" state="off" />
            <motor id="1" state="forward" />
            <motor id="2" state="reverse" />
            <motor id="3" state="off" />
            <motor id="4" state="off" />
        </motors>
        <leds>
            <led id="0" state="on" />
        </leds>
</avengerState>
```

Here is my parser:

```
def parseXml(file):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(file)
    motor = [[]]
    led = [[]]

    #it gets all the attributes within the motor child

    motorlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('motor')
    i = 0
    for s in motorlist :
        motor[i].append(motorlist[i].attributes['id'].value)
        motor[i].append(motorlist[i].attributes['state'].value)
        if(i<motorlist.length-1):
            motor.append([])
        i = i+1

    # it gets all the attributes within the led child

    ledlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('led')
    i = 0
    #led_pin_num = i #starting of LEDS for the pins dictionary
    while(i<ledlist.length):
        led[i].append(ledlist[i].attributes['id'].value)
        led[i].append(ledlist[i].attributes['state'].value)
        if(i<ledlist.length-1):
            led.append([])
        i = i+1
```

So for each motor[i] and led[i], I have a "motori" object, with the methods rotateClockwise, rotateCounterclockwise, and turnOff (turnOn and turnOff for ledi objects). I would like to call these methods on these objects depending on what state the motor is in in the XML file.

i.e.

motor id="0" state="off" ---- I would like to call motor0.turnOff()

motor id="1" state="forward" ---- I would like to call motor1.rotateClockwise()

etc...

How would I implement this in my parser? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can hava a dict store the map from "off" to turnOff() ..etc..

```
action = {
    "off" : MotorClass.turnOff,
    "forward" : MotorClass.rotateColckwise
}
```

then `action["off"](motor0)` will do his job. If your code need to be more complicated then, you can checkout the built-in function `apply`.